# AutoComplete Auto Select Auto Submit

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#search").autocomplete({
    source:'/autocomplete.php',
    minLength:3,
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 100,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#searchForm").submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
<form method="post" action="/reports/report.php" id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="q" size="35" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Okay, this is the situation. This is a special case of AutoComplete. The autocomplete.php script does an exact search to return only one match. It works. What we want is that it is not displayed to the end-user. Instead, the form is auto submitted using the returned match value. Having no luck. Obviously the select: would not work in this case. Need to auto select the returned value, and then auto submit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing

> [response( event, ui )](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response)               Type: autocompleteresponse
>
> Triggered after a search completes, before the menu is shown. Useful
>   for local manipulation of suggestion data, where a custom source
>   option callback is not required. This event is always triggered when a
>   search completes, even if the menu will not be shown because there are
>   no results or the Autocomplete is disabled.
>
> **event**
>
> Type: Event
>
> **ui**
>
> Type: Object
>
> - **content** Type: Array Contains the response data and can be
>     modified to change the results that will be shown. This data is
>     already normalized, so if you modify the data, make sure to include
>     both value and label properties for each item.

---

html

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <form method="post" action="/echo/json/" id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="q" size="35" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</div>
```

css

```
.ui-menu-item, .ui-helper-hidden-accessible {  
    display:none;
}
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var data = ["c++"
                , "php"
                , "coldfusion"
                , "javascript"
                , "asp"
                , "ruby"
               ];

    var elem = $("#search");
    elem.autocomplete({
        autoFocus:true,
        delay:100,
        minLength: 3,
        source: data,
        response: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(event, ui.content[0]);
            var form = $(this).parent("form");
            $.post(form.attr("action")
            , {json:JSON.stringify({"q" : ui.content[0].value})}, "json")
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log("post response:", data)
            }, function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log(errorThrown)
            })
        }
    });
    $("input[type=submit]").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x1h8cjLk/

Comment: Unfortunately, same result. I enter text, and see pull-down with response from autocomplete.php. If I select it, nothing. However, desired action is for form to autosubmit using response.

Comment: Checked `network` tab ? Is form _not_ being submitted to `/reports/report.php` ?

Comment: Yes, only shows submitting to autocomplete.php, and not /reports/report.php

Comment: Yes, it works beautifully. I may not have been clear. Yours posts transparently in the background. In our case, it is to be like the user submitted the form. For example, user enters text. The autocomplete.php script funds a match which it returns. Then, the form is auto submitted with result as input. User then sees the posted result page (report.php).

Comment: @DanielAbrams Can display response from `report.php` , `data.q` within `.then()` callback .

Comment: You can see it in action here at my client's website: http://www.badnumbers.com/ (just enter any phone number on page (with or without hyphens) in search box.